# cakephp 3.0 hidden form value and name

Tags: cakephp, hidden-field, formhelper

I want to create a hidden form input where I want to put my hidden value I want my form like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="d_id" value="2">
```

How can I create a form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey I find a solution cakephp3.0  if you want to add a hidden form with name and value I had try this code :

```
 echo $this->Form->hidden('d_id', ['value'=>$id]);
```

to get this value

```
<input type="hidden" name="d_id" value="2">
```